# Understanding the Frobenius Norm for Sparse Coding

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question regarding sparse coding, Non-negative sparse coding.

**Iterate until convergence:**

$ \mathbf{A_i} \leftarrow \arg \! \min_{A \geq 0} || \mathbf{X}_i - \mathbf{B}_i\mathbf{A}||_F^2 + \lambda \sum_{p,q} \mathbf{A}_{pq}$

I have recently been researching the Frobenius Norm and it seems as though it is the standard for methods like numpy in Python.

My question is how do I get the output $n \times m$ from the norm expression when:

$\mathbf{X} \sim T \times m$

$\mathbf{A} \sim n \times m$

$\mathbf{B} \sim T \times n$

If possible please give a small example of code reproducing the result.